# Why isn't reveal.js slide notes mode advancing fragments?

Tags: fragment, slide, reveal.js

I have been working on some slides using reveal.js, and they're being hosted on gh-pages.  I have encountered a strange problem that I was hoping someone could help with.

Looking at my slides, I hit "s" to enter Slide Notes mode.  The window appears correctly, the timer starts, and all that good stuff.  The presentation and slide notes windows stay in sync when it comes to advancing to the next slide at the right time.

The problem is that when I advance the slides hoping to show the next fragment, the fragments advance ONLY in the window that has focus.   In other words, if I focus on the Slide Notes window and hit the right key, then the slide notes window correctly shows the next fragment but the presentation does not; if I focus on the Presentation window and hit the right key, then the presentation correctly shows the next fragment but the slide notes do not.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like this bug that has been fixed before you posted your question:
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/538
What version of reveal.js are you running?